# Language Support menu won't open

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, language-support

Currently running Lubuntu 16.10. I have tried to open the language support menu many times, meaning to add Hebrew to my input languages (assuming that's the menu I should be looking at). Every time I open Language Support I get another window that opens saying "Checking available language support". A progress bar then quickly fills up and the window closes along with the language support window. Is there a way for me to fix this problem and access language support? Alternatively, is there a way to add Hebrew to my keyboard without having to open the language support menu?

Comment: The first window ought to be kept open when the other has checked for available language support. Can you please open a terminal window, run the command `gnome-language-selector` and let us know possible error messages by editing your question.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson 
ValueError: unknown locale: en_IL

Comment: Ok... Then please show us the output of the `locale` command.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson
LANG=en_IL
LANGUAGE=en_IL:en
LC_CTYPE="en_IL"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IL"
LC_TIME="en_IL"
LC_COLLATE="en_IL"
LC_MONETARY="en_IL"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IL"
LC_PAPER="en_IL"
LC_NAME="en_IL"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IL"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IL"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IL"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IL"
LC_ALL=

Comment: Looks ok. This is odd; I'm not able to reproduce the problem with the en_IL locale. Can you please try the `gnome-language-selector` command again and show us the _full_ output you see in the terminal window when it fails.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson
http://pastebin.com/2HYNPACw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paste of the terminal output shows where in the code the error happens. It's a Python bug, and related to the fact that the `en_IL` locale is relatively new.

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2+ (default, Sep 22 2016, 12:18:14) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160927] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, 'en_IL')
'en_IL'
>>> mylocale = locale.getlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 577, in getlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 486, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: en_IL
>>> quit()
```

This means that with the current locale setting you might encounter problems also with other Python applications, so I would suggest a workaround for now: Replacing `en_IL` with `en_IL.UTF-8` makes Python shut up.

- Open a terminal window and run

  ```
  sudo update-locale LANG=en_IL.UTF-8
  ```
- Log out and log in again
- Open *Language Support* without a crash

I reported the issue in [bug #1646260](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1646260).

Comment: The menu now opens without crashing. Upon marking Hebrew and clicking "Apply" in the Install/Remove Languages window, I get:
"Failed to download package files
Check you internet connection
Details:
Failed to fetch http://
"
Should I post a separate question for this and mark this one as answered or keep working on it under this question?

Comment: @AlonG.: I suggest that you first try again. If you get the same error, then open _Software & Updates_ and change the download server to something else but "Server for Israel", for instance "Main server".

Comment: Tried again but problem persisted. Changing the download server worked. Thank you!